# MVC multiple similar models

Tags: .net

I have a class Age with properties "AgeID" and "Name", and this code:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString AgeToCommaSeparated(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<Age> AgeList)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var age in AgeList)
        {
            sb.Append(age.Name);
            sb.Append(",");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
    }
```

Then I have lots of other classes similiar to Age, like Gender with "GenderID" and "Name".

Is there a way to make the AgeToCommaSeparated function generic so I can pass any class to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a common interface, something like this:

```
    public interface ICommaSeparable
    {
        string Chunk { get; set; }
    }

    public class Age : ICommaSeparable
    {
        public string Chunk { get { return AgeID; } }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int AgeID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gender : ICommaSeparable
    {
        public string Chunk { get { return GenderID ; } }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int GenderID { get; set; }
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString AgeToCommaSeparated(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, IEnumerable<ICommaSeparable> SeparableList)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var sep in SeparableList)
        {
            sb.Append(sep.Chunk);
            sb.Append(",");
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
    }
```

Comment: thanks - what if Gender uses GenderID, and Age uses AgeID instead of ID, and we need to reference ID from the AgeToCommaSeparated function?

Comment: I'd delegate everything to the interface that is used there. See update. If you can't or don't want to touch your Gender and Age classes then you can use reflection or what Aliostad suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx):

```
 String.Join(",", ageList.Select(x=>x.Name));
```

---

## UPDATE

You may do this to make your life easier but careful that compiling and running an expression is costly (that is what MVC does anyway but it uses caching inside):

```
public static class JoinExtensions
{
    public static string Join<TModel, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TModel> enumerable, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var compiled = expression.Compile();
        return string.Join(",", enumerable.Select(compiled));
    }
}


public class Age
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    public string GenderId { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
IEnumerable<Age> ages = new[]
                                    {
                                        new Age(){Name = "1"}, new Age(){Name = "2"}, new Age(){Name = "3"}, 
                                    };

Console.WriteLine(ages.Join(x => x.Name)); // outputs "1,2,3"
```

You may use this **for any class**. For example:

```
public class Gender
{
    public string GenderId { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
IEnumerable<Gender> genders = new[]
                                    {
                                        new Gender(){GenderId = "16"}, new Gender(){GenderId = "22"}, new Gender(){GenderId = "35"}, 
                                    };

Console.WriteLine(genders.Join(x => x.GenderId));
```

Comment: this is not what I'm asking. I'm asking if there is a way where I can pass Gender to the AgeToCommaSeparated function to make it generic